# .map() on javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, typescript

is there a way to map my `window._someProp` like if I would do it in TypeScript/Knockout:

```
window._someProp.map(b => ko.mapping.fromJS(b, {}, new typescriptModule.CustomClass()))
```

Wha's the best way in plain JavaScript or Jquery ?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to [loop through an object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties).

You could use the `Object.keys` method and `Object.assign` to extend an object's properties.

```js
var exampleExtend = function(obj) {
  Object.assign(obj, {
    extended: true
  });
};

var exampleObj = {
  first: {
    'a': 1
  },
  second: {
    'b': 2
  }
};

Object.keys(exampleObj)
      .forEach(function(k) { exampleExtend(exampleObj[k]); });

console.log(exampleObj);
```

To `map` an array, use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). E.g.: `[1,2,3].map(function(v) { return v * 2; })` produces a *new* array `[2,4,6]`.

Comment: Thanks, but Visual Studio will show me an syntax error for using `=>`...

Comment: I've rewritten the examples to use regular functions instead of arrow functions.